# Perl command-line script and shell variables: How to quote?

Tags: perl, variables, unix, quotes

I have a shell script (csh) calling Perl like this:

```
set SHELL_VAR = "foo"
set RES = `perl -e 'my $perl_var = uc("$SHELL_VAR"); print "$perl_var\n"'`
echo $RES
```

I did not manage to use single or double quotes properly, no matter which combination I tried.

How do I properly mix variables in Perl and shell?

Both are starting with `$`. Double quotes use variable values, but returns

> error `perl_var: Undefined variable.`

in shell. Enclosing a Perl script by single quotes led to an empty result. Escaping like `\$perl_var` does not succeed either.

Comment: have you tried using `escape "\"` for it?

Comment: See [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot), especially the section 4. QUOTING.

Comment: @NoobEditor: Yes, I tried it as mentioned in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution, you can simply concatenate several expressions, i.e. you can write

```
set XYZ = "foo"`date`bar$HOST'gugus'
```

for example. This is a concatenation of

```
foo + `date` + bar + $HOST + gugus
```

Thus the following works:

```
set SHELL_VAR = "foo"
set RES = `perl -e 'my $perl_var = uc("'$SHELL_VAR'"); print "$perl_var\n"'`
echo $RES
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert the value of a shell var into a Perl literal of a program that's in a command line. That's two levels of escaping! Instead, just pass it to Perl as an argument.

```
% set SHELL_VAR = "foo"
% set RES = `perl -e'print uc($ARGV[0])' "$SHELL_VAR"`
% echo "$RES"
FOO
```

---

Doh! It's not quite right.

```
csh% set SHELL_VAR = foo\"\'\(\ \ \ \$bar
csh% set RES = `perl -e'print uc($ARGV[0])' "$SHELL_VAR"`
csh% echo "$RES"
FOO"'( $BAR
```

I should get

```
FOO"'(   $BAR
```

In `sh`, I'd use `` RES="` ... `" `` aka `"$( ... ")`, but I don't know the `csh` equivalent. If someone could fix the above so multiple spaces are printed, I'd appreciate it!

```
sh$ shell_var=foo\"\'\(\ \ \ \$bar
sh$ res="$( perl -e'print uc($ARGV[0])' "$shell_var" )"
sh$ echo "$res"
FOO"'(   $BAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push your `SHELL_VAR` into the environment and let Perl pull it from there:

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv SHELL_VAR "foo"
set RES = `perl -e 'my $perl_var = uc($ENV{SHELL_VAR}); print "$perl_var\n"'`
echo $RES
```

Note that the `setenv` command lacks the expicit '=' for assignment.  The environmental variable is availab e to Perl from the %ENV hash with the variable name as its key.